# What do the prime factors of a number tell us about the number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I'm sorry for such a vague question, but I couldn't make it more plain. The other day i was working with a solution to a problem and out of curiosity i decomposed the number into its prime factors and noticed an interesting pattern. The number $216$ distribute in $2,3,2,3,2,3$ and when i grouped it, i had three pairs of 6's which then i could express as $6^3$. What other information could i gather by decomposing a number into its factors or prime factors? What does it say about components of the number?

P.S I'm interested in further readings and external links, too.

Comment: Being a cube means it's the volume of a cube with side length $6$, which may make geometric sense for done problems.

Comment: You may have stumbled onto the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.  Every number has a unique prime factor decomposition.  Every combination of prime factors is a factor and every factor is a combination of prime factors.

Answer (score 3):

When you know the prime factorisation, you can find the amount of divisors. If you have a prime factorisation $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ with $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_k$ different primes and $e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_k$ positive integers, you can find that the number of positive divisors equals $(e_1+1)(e_2+1)\cdots(e_k+1)$.

Example: $216=2^3\cdot 3^3$, so it has $(3+1)(3+1)=16$ positive divisors.

Is this an example of what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know what kind of numbers and how many could have produced it too. Generally I'd like to know more about solutions and backtracking previous steps, ex. if i knew that there were 3 numbers involved to product the final answer I could have known if these numbers were odd, even.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it's more interesting when a number has no prime factors, i.e., it is a prime number. However, being able to break a number into its prime factors can assist with mental calculations. To use your example,

> $72\times3=(9\cdot8)\cdot3=2^3\cdot3^2\cdot3=2^3\cdot3^3=6^3=216$

Instead of actually multiplying 72 and 3, I broke 72 into its prime factors and found the result will be a perfect cube. Assuming you know the perfect cubes up to $10^3$, this would be quicker than actually carrying out the multiplication.